'IEnumerable<<anonymous type: DateTime DateTime, int NewCustomerCount, int NewBookingCount>>
public async Task<IActionResult> GetMemberAndBookingLineChartData()
{
    var bookingData = _unitOfWork.Booking.GetAll(u => u.BookingDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30) && u.BookingDate.Date <= DateTime.Now).GroupBy(b => b.BookingDate.Date).Select(u => new
    {
        DateTime = u.Key,
        NewBookingCount = u.Count(),
    });
    var customerData = _unitOfWork.User.GetAll(u => u.CreatedDAt >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30) && u.CreatedDAt.Date <= DateTime.Now).GroupBy(b => b.CreatedDAt.Date).Select(u => new
    {
        DateTime = u.Key,
        NewCustomerCount = u.Count(),
    });

    var leftJoin = bookingData.GroupJoin(customerData, booking => booking.DateTime, customer => customer.DateTime, (booking, customer) => new
    {
        booking.DateTime,
        booking.NewBookingCount,
        NewCustomerCount = customer.Select(x => x.NewCustomerCount).FirstOrDefault()
    });
    var rightJoin = customerData.GroupJoin(bookingData, customer => customer.DateTime, booking => booking.DateTime, (customer, booking) => new
    {
        customer.DateTime,
        customer.NewCustomerCount,
        NewBookingCount = booking.Select(x => x.NewBookingCount).FirstOrDefault(),
    });

    //var mergedData = leftJoin.Union((rightJoin).OrderBy(x => x.DataTime).ToList());
    var mergedData = rightJoin.Union(leftJoin.OrderBy(x => x.DateTime)).ToList();

    var newBookingData = mergedData.Select(x => x.NewBookingCount).ToArray();
    var newCustomerData = mergedData.Select(x => x.NewCustomerCount).ToArray();
    var categories = mergedData.Select(x => x.DataTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")).ToArray();
    List<CharData> charDataList = new()
    {
        new CharData
        {
            Name="New Bookings",
            Data=newBookingData
        },
        new CharData
        {
            Name="New Members",
            Data=newCustomerData
        }

    };
    LineChartVM lineChartVM = new()
    {
        Categories = categories,
        Series = charDataList
    };

    return Json(lineChartVM);
}

Error is
var mergedData = rightJoin.Union(leftJoin.OrderBy(x => x.DateTime)).ToList(); 

is not working.
Please give me a solution

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. What I mean is that "it doesn't work, please solve for me" isn't a proper problem statement. What behavior are you expecting? Where is it going wrong? How is it going wrong? What is the behavior you're getting that is not what you expected?
